# get the ID of the current windows phone 7 device

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there a way that I can uniquely identify the windows phone device that my app is running on? Is there a windows phone device ID or something?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037862/will-there-be-a-unique-and-unchanging-device-id-that-apps-have-access-to-window

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try:

```
DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("DeviceUniqueId")
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941122(v=VS.92).aspx

Answer (score 19):

```
object uniqueID;
if (Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties.TryGetValue("DeviceUniqueId", out uniqueID)==true) {
  byte[]bID=(byte[])uniqueID;
  string deviceID=Convert.ToBase64String(bID);   // There you go
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Or you can use a globally unique identifier (GUID) in general
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx
And save that ID on local storage.

```
deviceID = Guid.NewGuid();
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["DeviceId"] = deviceID;
```

Comment: storing on local storage i forgot to mention